# Crawling Hidden Fields with PowerShell Created Crawled Properties

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, managed-property

I've been trying to add `ows__vti_ItemHoldRecordStatus` as a crawled property to allow a search of held documents. (It appears to correspond to the hold status of an SPListItem.)  I can successfully add it as an Integer crawled property with PowerShell, with search indexing turned on, but after doing a full crawl, the crawl property always shows as having zero documents, even after putting several documents on hold and recrawling. And so the associated managed property doesn't show any results.

Looking at the SPField for `_vti_ItemHoldRecordStatus`, the NoCrawl property is false.  Is there any way to get SharePoint Enterprise search to index the hidden field?  I have only seen conflicting opinions in newsgroups on the question.  Are there any workarounds to force SharePoint Enterprise Search to index the field?

Answer (score 1):

As I observed, hidden fields are not being crawled. You can "hide" a field by setting all the `ShowInXXX` properties to false to avoid showing up in the forms.